# Smarty + Prestashop: Include template if exists

Tags: syntax, smarty, prestashop

I've got the following code, which I would like to include a template if it exists otherwise fallback to outputting the content plainly.

```
{if $smarty->template_exists("$tpl_dir./cms.tpl")}
   {include file="$tpl_dir/$cms->link_rewrite.tpl"}
{ else }
   {$cms->content}
{ /if }
```

As far as I understand my syntax is correct, but I could be wrong as I am new to this. Any idea what I am doing wrong (I'm thinking maybe concatenation)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your file is in the same folder:

```
{assign var="file" value="`$smarty.current_dir`/file_name.tpl"}
{if $file|file_exists}
{include file=$file}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like concatenation problem. Use "backticks" to evaluate a Smarty variable:

```
$smarty->template_exists("`$tpl_dir`/cms.tpl")
```

For more information see [Embedding Vars in Double Quotes](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl)